# How to determine which "+" key was pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a request to replicate the + key as the tab key when the plus key on the number pad side is pressed.

It seems the plus key above letters where shift key is needed, and the plus key where numbers are in a keypad configuration both have a numeric number of 43.

How can I determine which + key was depressed?

Update:
I was using this example, "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_keycode"  as pointed below this was not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keycodes for each key is different. Numeric keypad = `107`, top row = `187`

You can use this to verify it on your own keyboard:

```js
$('#text').on('keydown', function (e) {
  $('label').text(e.which);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<label></label>
```

You can also use the `key` property in modern browsers (IE9+) to detect which key was output without having to worry about exactly which keys were used to generate it:

```js
$('#text').on('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.key == '+')
    console.log('You typed a plus symbol!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<label></label>
```

Comment: okay thank you. Hmm I was using this version:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_keycode

and they were coming up 43

Comment: Don't use W3Schools - their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is a far better resource.

Comment: Ah, well looks like that was my problem then!  Thanks for getting me unstuck.

Comment: Glad to help. Also note that I edited in another method you can use which is agnostic of any `keyCode` irregularities.

Answer (score 1):

The two keys produce two different key codes. You can test for the correct one:

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(evt){
  switch (evt.keyCode){
    case 107:
      console.log("You pressed '+' on the number pad");
      break;
    case 187:
      console.log("You pressed SHIFT '+' on main keyboard");
      break;    
  }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Just click once over here to give the "document" focus and then press the + key(s)
```